# Which fonts are standard for HTML on new generation browser?

Tags: html, css

When I started working on HTML there were only a little choice of font we could use for HTML rendered on every browser

Arial, Verdana, Times new roman, Georgia. Now, from 2003 the browser changed a lot, are there any new compatible fonts for every browser or for fonts we are still back in the early 2k years?

Comment: Every font is compatible with every browser.

Comment: you can include any font ....

Comment: by rendered on every browser I was meaning, as some user suggested, "web safe" so build in on every OS, or simply, a font that can be allways viewed the same on every browser/user/planet will surf my page.

Comment: This is a question for our sister site [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Naraj, I think what you're referring to are `web-safe fonts.` These are fonts that every user has on their machine.

Before I get into that, let me try to explain how font loading works. When you visit a website, the `CSS` file tells your computer what font file to look for. If you don't have that font file on your computer, it won't display! Luckily, browsers are smart and will fall back on defaults, like Arial, in cases like this.

Anyway, that list of fonts you're referencing is a list of fonts that most computers come with when you get them out of the box. Because of this, it's very likely that the user will have them, and the website will display properly if you reference them (rather than falling back on an alternative). Fonts like Helvetica, on the other hand, won't be on every machine, since it doesn't come with a PC. If you try to use Helvetica on your website, most PC users won't see it displayed!

With this said, you can now technically use any font on any website. This is through a CSS rule `@font-face`. What this does is lets you point to the font's location on a server, where the user can then download and use it.

There are two points of concern with using `@font-face`. The first is that the user has to download the font, so it adds a bit of lag to your page displaying. The second, and more crucial, point of concern is that you need to have the license of a font to use it. You can't just upload Helvetica on your server, because somebody else owns the font. You need to buy the license from a Font distributor website like https://typekit.com/ to be able to use them like this!

As others have mentioned, there are great web services that let users `@font-face` fonts, like [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace:select).

With all of this said, that list of `web-safe fonts` hasn't changed much. If you don't use `@font-face`, you should probably stick to that same list of fonts from 2003. [Here's an updated list](http://www.ctc-aspire.co.uk/blog-post-36-web-safe-fonts-157-34.html) from this year.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the answer is in the last paragraph of this good man's post: " that list of web-safe fonts hasn't changed much". 

The other people are trolling or don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers are kind of irrelevant here. Fonts come from the 'system', meaning the computer a particular user is on, not the browser itself.

Fonts are loaded from the local machine.

There are many font services out there now though. A good free one is Google fonts:
http://www.google.com/webfonts

Give that a try!

Answer (score 1):

None. There are no “web-safe fonts”. There is not a single font that we can expect to be available in all browsing situations. This depends on systems (computers), not browsers. The point is that fonts are shipped with an operating system and with some application software, but normally not with a browser.

Even Arial, Verdana, Times New Roman, and Georgia exist in different versions (so using a particular font family name, you may get slightly different results), and they are missing from some computers. Android, for one, has none of them (and the fonts available on Android are not pre-installed in other systems, so this alone proves that there are no web-safe fonts).

Downloadable fonts, also known as web fonts, used via `@font-face`, have been often been described as letting you to embed any font on your pages so that everyone sees the text in that font. This is partly true, but just partly, and with many pitfalls, and a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up some things. If you define a font - using the face attribute- the browser try to load this font from client filesystem. If he cannot find it he use the configured default font. The font list will also be read from client filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

With most modern browsers you can render any font you want on any OS/Browser using Web Fonts.

Of course many fonts are OS specific so fonts that would would render on OS X wont be available on Windows.

Web Fonts fixes this. Google provide hosted web fonts: http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 0):

You can use any font you want. If that font is available in the user's computer, it will show correctly, otherwise, the browser will default to a certain 'standard' font. If you want to use a custom font that doesn't come with some OSs (or all of them) then you need to use CSS3 @font property, Google Fonts, or other solutions.